# Is it possible to create a segment with tab on the left

Tags: semantic-ui

I would like to do like the [example tabs](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html#tabular) but instead of having the tab on top or bottom, I need them to be on the left.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The top and bottom tabs are more nicely attached to the segment, but there are some examples of tabular menus to the side of segments in http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html#tabular.